# Windows 10 Camera app error - missing camera roll?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, camera

My Camera app hasn't been working for at least a couple of months now on my Windows 10 laptop (which is fully updated). I made the mistake of trying to get my camera roll to automatically sync with OneDrive by using the "move" option under properties to permanently move it into One Drive. The Camera app just opens now with a black screen, displays an error message, and closes immediately as soon as I click Ok on the error message. A new error popped up yesterday that made a lot more sense but that I'm unable to fix by myself. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix the problem that causes these types of error messages [shown below]?

"Something went wrong. You can't take pictures without a Camera Roll, but it looks like you removed yours from this device. To fix this, reconnect the USB or SD card where you moved your Camera Roll."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Seems I'd deleted camera roll from my ext. HD and fortunately, had not emptied my recycle bin. So restored the LG HD G and bingo - camera now working.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "Camera Roll" folder from one drive back to "Pictures" folder on drive C. If the copy doesn't work try using the "Cut" command

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately :(